# adding specified elements to textbox from xml if a condition is true

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to add strings from an XML file to a textbox, but with no success yet.What i want to do is go through the "date" elements, and if "bejovo" has a match with "date"element, then put the element "name" value in a List, and sum the price.Here is my code.

```
if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                var c = from x in doc.Descendants("order")
                        where x.Element("date").Value == bejovo
                        select new
                        {
                            //??
                        };
                foreach (var item in c)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = item.ToString();                    
                }
            }
```

And here is my XML file:

```
<user id="0">
    <order id="0">
      <date>2012.11.20. 1:29:20</date>
      <menuelem db="0">
        <name>Pizza</name>
        <price>1290</price>
      </menuelem>
      <menuelem db="1">
        <name>Coke</name>
        <price>300</price>
      </menuelem>
    </order>
  </user>
<user id="0">
    <order id="1">
      <date>2012.11.19. 21:49:29</date>
      <menuelem db="0">
        <name>Milk</name>
        <price>200</price>
      </menuelem>
    </order>
  </user>
```

So in case bejovo="2012.11.20. 1:29:20",then my result must be "Pizza" and "Coke" and the price is 1590.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely this code has no validation:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("In.xml");
var c = from x in doc.Descendants("order")
        where x.Element("date").Value == "2012.11.20. 1:29:20"
        select new
        {
            Names = string.Join(", ", x.Elements("menuelem")
                                       .Elements("name")
                                       .Select(s => s.Value)),
            Price = x.Elements("menuelem")
                     .Elements("price")
                     .Select(s => decimal.Parse(s.Value))
                     .Sum()
        };
foreach (var item in c)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}\tprice:{1}", item.Names, item.Price);
}
```

The output goes like: `Pizza, Coke  price:1590`

Answer (score 0):

Might try something along these lines. Below code is untested, not able to load up and test in Visual Studio at the moment.

```
var items = doc
   .Elements("user")
   .Elements("order")
   .Where(o => (string)o.Element("date") == bejovo)
   .Elements("menuelem")
   .Select(m => new 
   { 
     Name = (string)m.Element("name"), 
     Price = (int?).Element("price") 
   };
var names = items.Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
var price = items.Select(i => i.Price).Sum();
```